# How can I simplify this maven multi-project (i.e., reactor) approach?

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-3

Suppose that I have many Github repos connected using a maven multi-module project (i.e., reactor), with a dependency tree like this...

```
A
  B
    C
  D
    F
    G
```

...and a pom structure like this:

```
                        - <parent><version>1-SNAPSHOT...
GitHub repo A - pom.xml - <artifactId>A</artifactId><version>2-SNAPSHOT...
                        - <dependencies><X><version>3-SNAPSHOT...
                        - <modules><module>B</module></modules>

                        - <parent><version>1-SNAPSHOT...
GitHub repo B - pom.xml - <artifactId>B</artifactId><version>2-SNAPSHOT...
                        - <dependencies><Y><version>3-SNAPSHOT...
```

...

If somebody updates C (e.g., adds a new Java method) and does `mvn deploy`, I want to automatically (i.e., Continuous Integration (CI)) rebuild both A and B to use C's latest version. To successfully accomplish that, I can use the [Jenkins Pipeline Maven Plugin (PMP)](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-maven/), such that when somebody updates C, Jenkins then triggers a build for B, which finally triggers A--in that order. While building those repos, maven downloads the latest SNAPSHOT for C, B, and A using a private Maven repo.

Now suppose I have a new requirement: remove PMP.

Problem: By removing PMP, if somebody updates C, PMP will not rebuild A, so A can NOT automatically use it. But another requirement says that A must use the latest version of C.

Question: How can I solve or improve this?

Comment: I think the answer to this question depends on your CI platform rather than being a maven question.

Comment: Are all these projects release at the same time ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, they are released at the same time with mvn release:prepare and mvn release:perform.

Comment: Then the suggestion of J Fabian Meier is the right way to go..single repo setup with all the modules...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always want to use the latest versions and rebuild everything, I would move all those git repos into one and use a multi-module project.

Comment: Many of these projects are multi-module, as suggested in the title, so I updated the question. Thanks. Given that, are you saying that multi-module across GitHub repo's leads to the PMP requirement?

Comment: I would not split a multi module project over different git repositories. It is much easier to have it in one git repository.